Need help removing black line on clothing
I added my sims to Blender 3.6 and noticed there was a black line shadow around her dress. How do I fix this problem?? I tried going to change the shader materials but that was not the problem at all. So I am not sure what happened.

PACKED BLENDER FILE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BaAZ2YmUC_9x2bnyxSFAWG7qlngXJ3RB/view?usp=sharing

Hello could you please share your file? Remove a part if you don't want to share the whole object, and use https://blend-exchange.com/

This looks like a deliberate mask in UV space, to achieve some effect .. if you didn't  make it yourself, just disconnect it altogether? Please show us your shader-nodes

@moonboots I just posted the link to my blend file above.

@RobinBetts I posted my shader-nodes above

Hello, could you please pack your image and share again?

@moonboots  Could you explain how do I pack the image and share again ? I am very very new to all of this.

File > External Data > Pack Resources

@moonboots I did exactly that and reuploaded for you.

thanks but your like asks for an authorization  ;)

@moonboots Okay I gave the access so you can review it

The black painting is here because your UV faces are over a black part of the Image Texture:

Just paint these black parts in white in Texture Paint mode:

